# Securing files in a mvc3 envrionment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, forms-authentication

So I have a MVC3 application that is using FormsAuthentication.  When a user logins, it creates the ticket, and directs them to their dashboard.

On the controllers, I am using the [Authorize] attribute to make sure that the actions are executed by authorized personnel only.

However, there is a part of the site that a user is allowed to upload files.  When the files get uploaded, the gets renamed to a random string with the correct extension (a guid without dashes).

How do I restrict unauthenticated and unauthorized users into this directory and to view these files based on the FormsAuthentication that I am using in the MVC3 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Web.Config` file with following entries inside the folder which has the files.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will prevent direct access to file in the folder for all users. Proved a UI to access the files. There you can check which files a user can access and prevent access to all files.

If you want to give direct access to the folder for particular set of authorized users then you need to add them to a role and give permission for that role.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So, this hasn't changed from WebForms to MVC3? Darn.  I thought there might be a clever way of doing this another way.

Comment: @Sean Asp.net runtime is common to both WebForms and MVC. Its not clear from your question that you want to give folder browsing access or you want to give permission to each file for a set of users.

Comment: Doesn't work. At least not for specific file inside the protected folder. I'm using MVC 4.0.